# Query to filter out rows that negate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to filter out rows with negating values. I.e. I want to remove all rows where one column matches and there are two rows with negating values. i.e. from

```
ID, Val, Details
0,   4,  "Details 0 1..."
1,   5,  "Details 1 1..."
1,   7,  "Details 1 2..."
1,  -5,  "Details 1 3..."
2,   9,  "Details 2 1..."
```

I would want

```
ID, Val, Details
0,   4,  "Details 0 1..."
2,   9,  "Details 2 1..."
```

because the rows 1,5... and 1,-5,... negate which marks that ID as invalid. I'm struggling to find a clean way to do this.

Comment: Why is 1,7 not included in expected result

Comment: Because if there is a negating value for the ID all values with that ID should be ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to verify that ID doesn't have "negating values":

```
select *
from tablename t
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t1
                  join tablename t2
                      on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Val = -t2.Val
                  where t1.ID = t.ID)
```